# Can a guest retrieve an authenticated user session variable?

Tags: meteor, session-variables

Can I retrieve a session variable (such as a counter) from an authenticated user and share that with any guest on a Meteor app? An example hopefully will give the question some clarity - An authenticated user (A taxi company) has a dynamic session variable which contains the number of drivers they have in a particular area, Can a guest (anybody that accesses the website) access that taxi company’s session variable directly? Or would I have to create a property in the company collection for the guest to access? (Trying to avoid unnecessary read/write).
Thanks

Comment: I would not call it a session variable. Just put it in a collection and publish it in a way that allows anyone to subscribe.

Comment: Cheers JeremyK - I'll have a look at that package now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session` Variables (and `reactive-var`, `reactive-dict`) are client side only, reactive datatypes.  They do not enable you to share data client <-> client, or client <-> server.

`Collections` are the simplest way to share data between the server and (potentially multiple) clients, and the simplest solution to the problem you are describing.

What you probably need on the server is a list of drivers in each area, even if you only publish the count of items in the list, possibly using this package to [publish counts](https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts).  This will enable you to know if a driver is already included in the count for an area, etc.